# Why can't I add item to my firebase database?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I try to make activity that user can add picture and description to my firebase database. I followed a tutorial on youtube to do this. After trying, all the functions in my app look normal but can't get the input result into firebase. My firebase code:

```
val filePathAndName="product_images/"+""+timeStamp
            val storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName)
            storageReference.putFile(image_Uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener {  taskSnapShot->
                    val uriTask=taskSnapShot.storage.downloadUrl
                    while(!uriTask.isSuccessful);
                    val downloadImageUri=uriTask.getResult()

                    if(uriTask.isSuccessful){
                        //url diterima
                        val hashMap:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap<String,String>()
                        hashMap.put("productId",timeStamp)
                        hashMap.put("productCategory",kategori)
                        hashMap.put("productWeight",berat_sampah)
                        hashMap.put("productDescription",deskripsi)
                        hashMap.put("productIcon",""+downloadImageUri)
                        hashMap.put("uid",""+firebaseAuth.uid)

                        val reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        reference.child(firebaseAuth.uid.toString()).child(Constants.PRODUCT).child(timeStamp).setValue(hashMap)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@AddProductActivity,
                                    "Berhasil Menambahkan",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                                ClearData()
                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener{e->
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@AddProductActivity,
                                    e.message,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                    }

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e->
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AddProductActivity,
                        e.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
```

Anyone know what i do wrong?

**EDIT:**
So after i read all the log, i find this error:

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://rongsokin-97e5c-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app
```

it says  database lives in another region, but i set my database in southeast asia same as my location, why is this happening?

Comment: Is your onFailure triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'd say it gets stuck at `while(!uriTask.isSuccessful)`, `while(!uriTask.isComplete)` was probably the intention here

Comment: @samthecodingman Oh yes, good catch ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that the problem is caused by `while(!uriTask.isSuccessful);`. As this could cause an infinite loop if `uriTask` failed.

I recommend making use of Task chaining (using the [`continueWith`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#continueWith(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20TContinuationResult%3E)), [`continueWithTask`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTContinuationResult%3E%3E)) or [`onSuccessTask`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#onSuccessTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.SuccessContinuation%3CTResult,%20TContinuationResult%3E)) methods) so that errors are easier to pick up and you don't end up with a mess of listeners.

```kotlin
val uploadAndSaveInDatabaseTask = storageReference.putFile(image_Uri)
    .onSuccessTask(taskSnapshot -> taskSnapShot.storage.downloadUrl)
    .onSuccessTask(downloadImageUri -> {
        val hashMap: HashMap<String,String> = hashMapOf(
            "productId" to timeStamp,
            "productCategory" to kategori,
            "productWeight" to berat_sampah,
            "productDescription" to deskripsi,
            "productIcon" to downloadImageUri,
            "uid" to firebaseAuth.uid
        );

        val reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(firebaseAuth.uid)
            .child(Constants.PRODUCT)
            .child(timeStamp);

        return reference.setValue(hashMap)
    });

uploadAndSaveInDatabaseTask
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@AddProductActivity, "Berhasil Menambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
        ClearData()
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Toast.makeText(this@AddProductActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I try to remove the while loop and my ```if(uriTask.isSuccessful)```(not the best idea) to test if that is the problem, but still nothing is showing in my database